# Is an encrypted pdf file as secure as an encrypted excel file?

Tags: excel, security, pdf, encryption

I need to export data from my application. I need to know the most secure format with regard to security between a PDF or an Excel file. Is an encrypted pdf file as secure as an encrypted excel file?

If you know another secure data format, please let me know.

Comment: The decision of whether or not to export a PDF or an excel file should be completely independent of the encryption you use to protect it.  Pick the file format that makes the most sense for your business/domain goals, *then* decide how you're going to encrypt it.

Comment: Secure *against what* ?

Comment: And what encryption? The format internal via password or an external one like GnuPG?

Comment: @TimWilliams Protect document from unwanted readers

Comment: @Robert 
I would not like the end user to need to download specific software such as GnuPG to open the document. So I imagine my answer is internally. What I really want is a mobile application that generates an encrypted document ...